# Examples of distributions with small $\ell_\infty$ norm?

Tags: probability-theory, supremum-and-infimum, empirical-processes

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I_{n \times n})$, so that $X$ is, in distribution, $n$ independent and identically distributed draws of a $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ random variable. Then it is well known that

$$
\mathbf{E} \|X\|_{\ell_\infty} = \mathbf{E} \sup_{1 \leq j \leq n} |X_j|= \Theta(\sqrt{\log n}). 
$$
I am wondering if there are distributions on $\mathbf{R}^n$ such that 
$$ \mathbf{E} \|X\|_{\ell_\infty} = \Theta(1).$$

This is of course possible by taking $X$ to have support on a finite or bounded set. However I am wondering if it possible that the above holds, while $X$ is supported on all of $\mathbf{R}^n$. The coordinates need not be independent.

Comment: It seems to me that something needs clarification. I guess that $X$ in your question means a family of random variables $X_n$ (one for each $n$). I also guess that you want each $X_n$ to be somehow "the same distribution just on spaces of differing dimensions". It's not obvious how to make this last notion precise to me in general since your example really relies on us having a good notion of what a Gaussian in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is. I'd guess you want to exclude $\tilde{X}_n = c_n X_n$ for suitable $c_n$ with $X$ as in the Gaussian example. I'm not sure what condition you want to exclude this.

Comment: I do think my post makes quite clear that there are asymptotics involved, necessitating as you say $X := X_n$, and the support being a subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$. I don't mind that Gaussians are included. I am wondering what else there is.

Comment: To be fair, your comment does apply in the following sense. Although satisfying the requirements, $X_n = (1/\sqrt{\log n}) N(0, I_n)$, is not interesting to me. I don't know how to make that formal though.

Comment: The point in your second comment is exactly what I was getting at. An extreme example is to take for each $n$,  $\tilde{X}_n$ to be absolutely any random variable in $L^1(\Omega; (\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot\|_\infty))$ with range $\mathbb{R}^n$ and then consider $X_n = \mathbb{E}[\|\tilde{X}_n\|_\infty]^{-1} \tilde{X}_n$. My point is that you obviously want some consistency in how the $X_n$ are chosen, but I don't see any good way of making that precise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for, but here's a few different observations:

1) You probably noticed this, but this isn't possible if $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ with the $X_i$ drawn i.i.d. from any common fixed distribution (that is, independent of $i$ or $n$, which seemed to be what you wanted to avoid) with support on all of $\mathbb{R}$. This is because for each $C>0$ and all $i\in [n]$ and $n$, $\Pr(\vert X_i\vert< C)=1-\gamma_C<1$ by the assumption of full support. Then of course,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[\|X\|_{\ell_{\infty}}]=\mathbb{E}[\sup_{1\leq i\leq n} \vert X_i\vert]\geq C\Pr(\sup_{1\leq i\leq n} \vert X_i\vert\geq C)= C(1-(1-\gamma_C)^n).
\end{equation}
This last term tends to $C$ with $n$, and as $C$ is arbitrary, this implies $\mathbb{E}[\|X\|_{\ell_{\infty}}]\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$. You could still do some sort of diagonal scaling across components to retain independence (but not identical distribution across components), but this doesn't seem too interesting to me.

2) As noted in the comments, it's not clear what exactly a satisfying example would be. One way to formalize it might be to say that all marginals are the same across components as well as $n$. This would rule out the scaling examples, for instance. Here's one potential example: to sample $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$, first sample $Y$ from any distribution with full support on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{E}[\vert Y\vert]<\infty$, and then set $X_i=U_iY$ where the $U_i$ are i.i.d. $\mathcal{U}[-1,1]$ random variables. This will have full support on $\mathbb{R}^n$, the components have identical marginals for every $i$ and $n$, and $\vert X_i\vert\leq \vert Y\vert$ so 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[\|X\|_{\ell_{\infty}}]\leq \mathbb{E}[\vert Y\vert]<\infty.
\end{equation}
In fact, offhand, I'm pretty sure you can easily show that the left side increases monotonically to $\mathbb{E}[\vert Y\vert]$.

Hope this is something like what you're looking for!